# I need to copy a database from one Redshift Cluster to another cluster

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I need help in moving a database from one Redshift cluster to another Redshift cluster. Here, I'm not copying a table. I want to copy a database. Could some one help me on this.

Comment: does the target already exist? so you are adding a new database to the existing target cluster?

Comment: When you say "copy a database", are you referring to the PostgreSQL "database" entity (where one cluster can have multiple databases created via the `CREATE DATABASE` command), or are you referring to the **complete contents of the Redshift cluster**? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details (eg your situation and why you wish to do so).

Comment: no @JohnRotenstein.. i want to move a particular database from one cluster to another, not all the contents.

Comment: What do you mean by "move a database, but not all the contents". Do you mean "move one specific database (created via `CREATE DATABASE`) within a cluster to another cluster, but not the other databases *within* that cluster"? I'm asking because many people get confused by the definition of "database".

Comment: to move one specific database (created via CREATE DATABASE) within a cluster to another cluster

Answer (score 1):

- **Using s3 as temp storage**

  If both clusters in the same region then
  UNLOAD to s3 from cluster 1
  then
  COPY from S3 to cluster2.
- **Using cluster snapshot.**

  Create a snapshot of the source cluster, then restore the snapshot as the destination cluster.
  If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a snapshot of the current database. And restore it once you create the new database.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Option 1: Take a snapshot and create a new cluster by restoring the snapshot and drop the databases which you do not require. You can have a cross region if required.

Option 2: Unload the table data from the current database to S3 and Copy the data to new database after you create a new one, here you need to manually create all the dependencies like users, groups, access, etc..